# Shifting the discussion to personae

Tags: word-choice, idioms

I wonder if there is any phrase or idiom to express a situation, where one of the discussion participants, lacking arguments to upkeep a constructive discussion, steers the direction to personae:

> -- ... So these are my arguments, proving that you are completely wrong. Do you agree?
>
> -- This is utter rubbish, only fools like you think that way!

Comment: _Argumentum ad hominem_ is what the Romans called it; in English it's just called "an ad hominem argument". I think the Latin was a translation from Greek; it's certainly common enough behavior to warrant a name.

Comment: Since the idiom tag is present, consider "slinging mud" or "resorting to personal attacks"

Comment: Thanks for your input, the replies to the other question does not exactly address my question.

Answer (score 1):

To build upon John Lawler's comment, this response could be termed an 'Ad Hominem Attack'. ('Attack against the Man')

This is a type of logical fallacy in which DebaterA attacks the character (and therefore credibility) of DebaterB.

http://www.logicalfallacies.info/relevance/ad-hominem/